# how to start an electron-application in a browser

Tags: angular, electron, hybrid

I downloaded an electron-angular4 project from "https://github.com/maximegris/angular-electron". It works perfect!

My question is: is there any simple way, to start it in a browser as Angular does.
My object is to develop a hybrid-project, which can be run as a desktop and as a web application.

Thank you!
Xinyu

Answer (score 0):

Your application is an Angular application so it can run in a browser. To do that with the project you have downloaded (which was generated with Angular CLI) just make sure you have Angular CLI installed globally then run `ng serve` from your project's root directory and navigate to http://localhost:4200 to see your app. Just be aware of this: if the code relies on some NodeJS libraries like 'fs' or 'os' they won't be available in the browser.

Comment: I have to remove "ejected":true in .angular-cli.json and comment the child_process in app.commoent.ts.
"ng serve" makes then no error. But the website shows just "Loading...". It cannot resolve <app-root>.
Did I do something wrong?

Comment: It depends, what's the error saying? As I said, if the project relies on some NodeJS libraries, you won't be able to run it in a browser.